# How can I apply Delphi XE2 skins to forms in a DLL?

Tags: delphi, skinning, vcl-styles

Using Delphi XE2, you have the option to embed custom styles (skins) to a VCL project.
Everything works fine. Now I have some forms into a separated dll that I show dynamically.
Of course those are not skinned. How can I rectify that?

I guess I must do some call to TVisualStyle somehow, but no luck.

**The host:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
var   
  l: THandle;   
  p: procedure (const h: THandle); stdcall; 
begin   
 l:= LoadLibrary('project1.dll');   
 if l > 0 then   
 begin
        @p:= GetProcAddress(l,'ShowIt');
        p(Application.Handle);
        FreeLibrary(l);   
  end; 
end;
```

**The dll:**

```
procedure ShowIt(const h: THandle);stdcall;
var
  form: TForm;
  b: TButton;
  han: THandle;
begin
  han:= Application.Handle;
  Application.Handle:= h;
  form :=Tform.Create(Application);
  b:= TButton.Create(form);
  b.Parent:= form;
  b.Caption:= 'ytes';
  b.Left:= 2;
  b.Top:= 2;
  form.ShowModal;
  form.Release;
  Application.Handle:= han;
end;

exports ShowIt ;
begin
end.
```

Pretty standard stuff. Now, what exactly must be done to make the dll form use the host's style theme?

Comment: Did you recompile the DLL with XE2?

Comment: It's a DLL rather than a package?

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't pick the original theme up.

Comment: You've not given any details of how the VCL is shared (if at all) and how the exe and DLL are separated - what goes where.

Comment: Do not call `Form.Release` there. That posts a message to the application's message queue, and that message won't get processed until the thread next processes messages, which isn't until *after* the DLL function returns to the caller. The caller unloads the DLL, so now you're stuck with a message on the queue addressed to a window that still exists, but whose code has already been unloaded from memory. Call `Free` instead. `Release` is for when an object wants to free itself from within one of its own message handlers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have two distinct instances of the VCL. You have set the style in the [`StyleServices`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Themes.StyleServices) instance owned by the executable, but your DLL has no knowledge of that. You could solve this by either:

1. Passing the style settings to a function in your DLL that applies those settings to the other `StyleServices` instance.
2. Use packages so that you only have a single VCL instance.

Comment: Thanks. I'll pass the skin name as a Pchar then (and embed the visuals styles a resources in the dll). Seems to work fine  that way. I'm not too kind about packages.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of trouble with this and it was because I was using `themes` rather than `VCL.THEMES` and `VCL.STYLES`.

Delphi was throwing up a `customeStyleException` saying "style not found" or `EcustomStyleException` "Feature not supported by this style"