# Fix VCL Styles Directory in Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, ide, styles, vcl, delphi-xe3

I have a problem about VCL Styles in Delphi IDE.
When I change VCL Style From default style to another style in delphi IDE and run program an "Style 'Style Name' not found" error comes up. I trying to find a option in IDE to fix Style directory, but I can't find any options. 
Please, help me to solve this problem and fixing IDE Options.
thanx a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oh, after a time, I found a way for solving this problem. for solving this problem must running the "redistsetup.bat" file. this file by default located in "C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0\Redist\redistsetup.bat".  (^_^)

Answer (score 4):

I found I was suddenly seeing this "Style 'Style Name' not found" error when as a result of removing a file from my project the line in my project file that shows

{$R *.RES}

was inadvertently replaced by

{R *.RES}

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem , after I added some styles in project ( option ) , I had error ' style not found " I remove all styles in project --> option but alwyse the same problème

After I go the source project I find those lines  ( TrySetStyle )

```
 begin

  TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Turquoise Gray');
  TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Cobalt XEMedia');
  Application.CreateForm(TFormLogin, FormLogin);
  Application.CreateForm(TFormMain, FormMain);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

The solution is just to remove those lines

But I think the probleme is some where the program  can't find the path

Comment: A solution to a different problem but it helped me - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the only supported way of fixing IDE issues is to run Delphi setup and choose Repair (if the problem is really the Styles folder)

You can use [Sysinternals' Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to check if your program (or the IDE) is failing to find/open a style file.

Also you may take a look at: [How can I apply Delphi XE2 skins to forms in a DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335976/how-can-i-apply-delphi-xe2-skins-to-forms-in-a-dll)

Comment: I think we can fix this missing dir via registery or a file; but I don't know which registry or file path. In Delphi Installation Path "..\Redist\styles\vcl" I can find style files; but I don't know why Delphi Can't use this files?!!! (o_o)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check this directory
C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\10.0\Styles

I have no idea and cannot reproduce the problem.

In the help file - Section Application Appearance.

Greetings
Mike